# Form validation using jquery method show() and hide()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a form for user details. I want to validate the form using jquery hide and show method. But I am doing something wrong as the required functionality is working. Where am I going wrong? I read other answers too on this topic but ain't getting the work done.

My form:

```
 <form id="uploadimageform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <input type="text" placeholder="first name" id="first" class="firstn" name="user[firstname]" /><br />
                <div class="firstname23">
                <p >Please fill the first name.</p>
                </div>
                <input type="text" placeholder="last name" id="last" class="lastn" name="user[lastname]" /><br />
                <div class="lastname23">
                    <p >Please fill the Last name.</p>
                </div>
                <input type="text" maxlength="10" placeholder="contact no." id="contact" name="user[contact_number]" onkeypress="return isNumberKey(event)" /><br />
                <input  type="address" placeholder="address1" id="addr1" name="user[address1]"/><br />
                <input  type="address" placeholder="address2" id="addr2" name="user[address2]"/><br />
                <input  type="address" placeholder="street" id="strt" name="user[street]"/><br />
                <input  type="address" placeholder="street1" id="strt1" name="user[street1]"/><br />
                <input  type="address" placeholder="city" id="city" name="user[city]"/><br />
                <input  type="address" placeholder="state" id="statee" name="user[state]"/><br />
                <input  type="address" placeholder="country" id="cntry" name="user[country]" /><br />
                <input  type="email" placeholder="email" id="email" class="emailn" name="user[email]" /><br />
                <div class="email23">
                    <p >Please fill the Email.</p>
                </div>
                <input  type="password" placeholder="password" id="paswrd" class="passn" pattern="^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?!.*\s).*$" name="user[password]" /><br />
                <div class="password23">
                    <p >Please fill the Password.</p>
                </div>

                <select name="user[gender]" id="gndr">
                    <option>Gender</option>
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select><br />
                <input type="file" name="user_photo" id="user_photo" /><br>
                <div class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" id="addbutton" onclick="">Submit </div>
            </form>
```

My Jquery validation:

```
$(".firstname23").hide();
        $(".lastname23").hide();
        $(".email23").hide();
        $(".password23").hide();

        $("#addbutton").click(function(){
            alert($(".firstn").val())
        if ($(".firstn").val() == '') {
            $(".firstname23").show();
        }
        if ($(".lastn").val() == '') {
            $(".lastname23").show();
        }
        if ($(".emailn").val() == '') {
            $(".email23").show();
        }
        if ($(".passn").val() == '') {
            $(".password23").show();
        }
        });
```

Comment: What about, at least, saying what doesn't work and what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: Currently, even if the first name, lastname, email and password fields are blank it still submits the form. I want them to be mandatory

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `required` attribute on your input fields to make sure that they are filled by the user:

```
<input required type="text" placeholder="first name" id="first" class="firstn" name="user">
```

Only [HTML5](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_required.asp) supports the `required` attribute for form elements.

It's going to be needed to change your HTML type and make sure that your files starts with something like that:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
...
```

You can remove then all slashes at the end of the tag from:

```
<input />
```

to:

```
<input>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Why doesn't it work? What happened when you tried that? How did you do it? etc. etc. etc.

Comment: @22anonymous This is not informative. What exactly doesn't work?

Comment: I have tried using "required" attribute, I have tried using the function in JS to validate the form this too ain't working. By function I mean I checked if these fields are empty then an alert should pop up asking to fill them. I used the above jquery method hide and show the div with the message on the blank field it ain't working too. By not working I mean even if the fields are empty and I hit submit button the form gets submitted without any error message or anything as such.

Comment: @22anonymous What are the first 2 lines of you `.html` file?

Comment: @22anonymous In case you run your jQuery validation in the head of the file, the way it looks now, it will not work. The easiest way is to make sure that the page finishes loading first by wrapping your code into ready function `$(function() {// your code is here});`.

Comment: My Jquery validation is inside $(function() { ...}); itself. It isn't inside head of .html file. Jquery file is a seprate file linked to the .html file via <script src="filename.js"></script>

Comment: Look, just post the whole thing on https://jsfiddle.net so I could test it. I have no idea what you mean by "it doesn't work".